# Memory leak iOS pre 5.0.

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, addsubview

I am struggling figuring out what is wrong with this code. I guess I don't quite understand the reference count. I always relied on ARC in the version of iOS. But I am supposed to do a quick upgrade to a code written in 4.0  to 7.0. Running the analysis shows the following error:

Method returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count
& Reference count incremented.

The object now has a +1 retain count at line `:[self changeSelectionTo:[[gregorian dateFromComponents:currentComps] retain]];`

Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1 at `[currentPageView selectDate:selected];`

I am new at IOS and I cannot seem to recognize the issue in this code. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<CalendarViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *selected;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<CalendarViewDelegate>)d {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]) {
    delegate = [d retain];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                 initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    [self createUIControls];

    NSDateComponents *currentComps =
    [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    currentDay = currentComps.day;
    currentMonth = currentComps.month;
    currentYear = currentComps.year;

    showingMonth = currentComps.month;
    showingYear = currentComps.year;

    [self updateLastAndNextMonthAttributes];

    [self updateMonthHeader];

    currentPageView = [[CalendarPageView alloc] initWithMonth:showingMonth
                                                      andYear:showingYear delegate:self];
    currentPageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, currentPageView.bounds.size.width, currentPageView.bounds.size.height);
    currentPageView.delegate = self;
    [pagesView addSubview:currentPageView];

// the memory leak issue seems to be in this area
    [self changeSelectionTo:[[gregorian dateFromComponents:currentComps] retain]];

    [currentPageView selectDate:selected];
    highlighted = nil;
```

Comment: Paste runtime crash info, you might be getting crash due to reason other than analyser suggested you. I guess your code is creating retain cycle as I can see you have retained the incoming delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If it say:

Method returns an Objective-C object with a `+0 retain count` & `Reference count incremented`.

The object now has a +1 retain count at line:

`[self changeSelectionTo:[[gregorian dateFromComponents:currentComps] retain]];`

then doesn't retain it.
Also it's bad practice to retain objects before passing them somewhere. Handlers should decide for themselves if they need their own object or not.

I think you need read this article about [memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: how would you rewrite the faulting lines? Thx

Comment: @user3170275, `[self changeSelectionTo:[gregorian dateFromComponents:currentComps]];`

Comment: if I remove the retain keyword, the code crashes actually after few clicks.